# iPhone Simulator can not open (localhost) http://127.0.0.1:8000/foo/bar/

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

iPhone Simulator can not open (localhost) `http://127.0.0.1:8000/foo/bar/`[image]

What is the reason?

Comment: The problem was somewhere else.

the endpoint /goto/ was redirecting  (if iPhone) to iTunes store link, which even when copy and paste breaks on iPhone simulator. Just it. End of the story.

Comment: use ngrok which really rocks... Check the below post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618330/android-emulator-not-connecting-to-localhost-api/52626534#52626534

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The iOS Simulator uses the host machine network so you should be able to just use localhost or your machines IP address, whichever IP your web service is listening on.

So, try out this:

```
http://localhost:8000/your_path
```