# Android emulator not connecting to localhost api

Tags: c#, android, api, http, xamarin

I have a Xamarin app and localhost API. I'm trying to connect to the API from the app, but it could not be found. I edited my `applicationhost.config` file and I tried `localhost`, `10.0.2.2` and my IP address in the call, but it was not working.

So, how do I configure simple API access?  (The API itself is working well)

Comment: use the IP address.  Test it using the browser on the device/emulator to rule out connectivity issues.  Also check your firewall settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Oke, but I tested it with my IP in emulator and It has not found yet. What do I check my firewall ? I do not know, what I should do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is simple workaround to connect `Emulator` & `Simulator` to `localhost` API.

[Download third party software NgRok for Windows](https://ngrok.com/download) at any specific location of your PC. It just contains one executable file called `ngrok.exe` (you not need to install it).

Now execute your service on your preferred browser. Than follow below steps.

- Open your `ngrok.exe` file path in command prompt

[image]

- Keep your service url (take from your browser) with prefix `ngrok http --host-header=rewrite` and hit enter.

[image]

- Now go to your browser where you have executed your service open new tab and type `localhost:4040` than press enter -->Go to `status` there you will find your public url which you can use in your mobile application.

[image]

Note: Url structure should be like this `public const string BaseUri = "https://8c56892f.ngrok.io/";` followed by `/` in last. Try not to append unnecessary `/`.

Benifits

1. You can debug services from one Visual Studio to another.
2. Your url will be active until you close command prompt.
3. In browser or command prompt track your requests status like `Ok`, `Not found` etc.

For more information visit this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/exposing-local-web-server-to-internet-using-ngrok/

Hope it help you.

Comment: Oh man. Yes, It is working! Thanks a lot! ( I have never seen anything like this before)

Comment: Even this is not helping me in flutter android and dot net server

Comment: @neena I followed all steps and its working in Flutter, using IIS Express (API developed in .NET Core).

Comment: Nice tool - just keep in mind the free version only allows sessions of 2 hours each, and the url they generate changes every time, which is pretty annoying

Answer (score 1):

That 10.0.2.2 address is used for the Google emulators. For the Microsoft emulator you want to use 169.254.80.80. If that doesn't work then it must mean you have the firewall on and it's blocking the traffic. That can be solved by adding a new incoming rule for the program or port.

Comment: Yes, It is true! I was debugging it. My android emulator use 10.0.2.2 adress. But, how to add a new incoming rule for the program or port ?

Comment: @DönciFekete Turn on your local server (WAMP, XAMP), Open Emulator and type 169.254.80.80 in the chrome or any browser in emulator and check if the wamp/ xamp page is showing or not. if it is not showing tell the error code what it is showing.

Comment: if you are using latest wamp server then follow steps at this link https://www.betterhostreview.com/access-wamp-server-local-network.html

Comment: I use RESTFull web service like in this example https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoREST/. So, I do not follow your instructions. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: If you are using local server to perform add, delete, edit etc operations then please follow the above steps if you are using an online server then check if you have given Internet permissions to your app

Comment: Just what I needed, I wonder why Google doesn't just use 127.0.0.1?