# Android Emulator Sending local request to Azure Api results in 400 error

Tags: android, azure, android-emulator, azure-functions, retrofit

Running into an issue where I can't send a request from my Android Emulator to my locally running Azure API. I keep getting a 400 error(Bad Request). Below is the sample request I'm sending. I can successfully reach my local Azure Api through postman. I have attached the code for the request and for the azure function below. Also I have set my permissions for my android project for android.permission.INTERNET

**Android Get Request**

```
    @Headers(
        "Accept-Encoding: chunked",
        "Content-Type: Application/Json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept: Application/Json",
        "Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"
    )
        suspend fun getLabel(
        @Path("labelId") labelId: Int
    ): LabelTag
```

**Azure Function**

```
        [FunctionName("GetLabel")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetLabel([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "label/{labelId}")]HttpRequestMessage req, int labelId, TraceWriter log)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            try
            {
                LabelService labelLogic = new LabelService();
                log.Info("Retrieving from database");
                var label = labelLogic.GetLabelById(labelId);
                if (label != null)
                {
                    log.Info("Retrieved from database");
                    response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, label);
                }
                else
                {
                    var errorMessage = "Failed to retrieve label";
                    log.Error(errorMessage);
                    response = req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorMessage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(e.Message, e);
                response = req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

**Screen shots**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you also added the permission android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE to your manifest?

Comment: Yeah I have added that one to my manifest as well

Comment: Found the answer from a previous stack overflow post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618330/android-emulator-not-connecting-to-localhost-api/52626534#52626534