# Issues connecting to C# API from Flutter app

Tags: flutter

I have an app that was originally written in android studio but I am trying to change it to be in flutter. Originally, I would enter data in the app and save it to my database, nothing complicated. I am however attempting to redo this in flutter.

**The Issue**

Utilizing the following code   `static const String _baseUrl = 'http://localhost:54553/api/TicketAPI/';` in my "postToApi" method I get a Connection Refused right off the bat. However, searching the site I came across a solution to use `10.0.2.2` instead of any IP or Localhost. That seemed to work but then I get an invalid host error.
Please see my code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TicketInfoApi {
  static const String _baseUrl =
      'http://localhost:54553/api/TicketAPI/';
  static Future<bool> postDataToApi({
    required String officerNumber,
    required int officerRank, //  
    String ticketNumber = "123rest",
    required String officerFirstName,
    required String officerLastName,
  }) async {
    final String apiUrl =
        '${_baseUrl}InsertTicket'; //  

    final body = json.encode({
      'officerNumber': officerNumber,
      'ticketNumber': ticketNumber,
      'officerFirstName': officerFirstName,
      'officerLastName': officerLastName,
    });

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
        },
        body: body,
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        return responseData != null;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit**

What I think is happening is, if the address is "localhost", the emulator is looking at it's self instead of my laptop.

Comment: `10.0.2.2` *is* a local IP address that might have been assigned to your machine earlier. I'm guessing your server is only listening on IPv4, but localhost resolves to IPv6 as well and it's prefered by Dart.

Comment: @lnl I'm doing more reading and it seems localhost is the "phone" not my machine. Trying to get a way for it to look at my machine

Comment: I used the answer from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618330/android-emulator-not-connecting-to-localhost-api/52626534#52626534